# Find a point where $f(P_0)=0$, with $f(x,y,z)= z^2+\frac{2}{x}-\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I need the derivative to show that the function $f$ is continuous. 
Let $f(x,y,z):\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y,z)= z^2+\frac{2}{x}-\sqrt{(y^2+z^2)}$ , $f \in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R^3})$. I assumed it was to get to the question I am asking you.

Comment: If you want to know the points $(\bar x, \bar y, \bar z) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ where $f(\bar x,\bar y,\bar z)=0$ you should study the implicit function defined by $f(x,y,z)=0$.

Comment: I did this and I thought about z being an implicit function of (x,y). Then I found out that (dz/dx)=(-(df/dx)/(df/dz))P0 and (dz/dy)=(-(df/dy)/(df/dz))P0. Found P0(-2/5 ; 5 ; 3)

Comment: So what do you need to know?

Comment: If it's right, and more importantly next thing to now is if x^2(dz/dx) + (1/y)(dz/dy)= 1/z. Have I to replace the partial derivatives in the equation to see if it is equal to 1/z?